# What does the curl --insecure option mean?

Tags: ssl, curl

## 1: According to another post on SO:

'-k/--insecure will "only make" curl skip certificate validation, it will not turn off SSL all together.'

If I am using SSL with curl, I still need a certificate file to figure out how to decrypt the message. SSL without a certificate file will never work. --insecure just means to blindly trust that the certificate file is valid.

Is that correct?

## 2: Chrome 'magically' recognizes certificates, curl does not.

Sites that work in Chrome don't work thru curl unless you use --cacert. I am guessing that's because certificates are a function of the application (browser) and not the OS.

Is that correct?

Comment: ssl only needs a cert on ONE side of the connection, which generally is the server. the only time YOU need a cert on the client is to prove your identity to the server. what you lose with the -insecure is verifying that the remote side is really what it is.

Comment: @MarcB you should make that an answer.

Comment: Very bad strategy; see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html).

Comment: @jww, funny thing is that this website is not secure :)